# OS X color panel magnifying glass returns a different color than PNG encoding

Tags: macos, colors, nscolorpanel

I have a PNG filled with `RGB(255, 255, 0)`, aka 'yellow':

[image]

When I inspect the yellow area **using the OS X color panel's magnifying glass**, it returns `RGB(255, 253, 56)`. The result is the same when the image is open in Pixelmator, Quicklook, Safari, or Preview.

When I inspect the same area using **Pixelmator's cursor RGB readouts**, it returns `RGB(255, 255, 0)`.

Why the inconsistency? I want the color panel to return `RGB(255, 255, 0)`; is that possible?

**Edit:** A bug report has been filed for this behavior. [Apple Bug Reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem) (search for issue `15914963`)

Comment: I thought it might be related to ColorSync, however, when I use the magnifying glass on the image you posted I get 249, 255, 25 instead of 255, 255, 0 no matter which ColorSync profile I choose.

Comment: Actually, what is really odd is if I use the magnifying glass, choose a color, then use the glass again to pick the color in the color picker that I just selected it will just keep shifting the color. With your yellow above if I keep selecting the color in the color picker it steadily turns green.

Comment: @Eidola I tried what you said; mine eventually turns into `RGB(243, 226, 197)`, kind of a beige skin tone mix. Once it reaches that point, it stays at that color. Very confusing...

Comment: My guess is there is a bug with the default implementation of the magnifying glass, it appears to not be taking into account the ColorSync profile. I even downloaded a "developer" color picker plugin which lets you pick raw rgb, device rgb and calibrated rgb... I get the same 249, 255, 25 in all three modes. Are you running 10.9.x by chance?

Comment: @Eidola Yep, Mac OS X 10.9.1 (13B42)

Comment: Same here, I am thinking that it is yet another bug with Mavericks, and we should probably go file bug reports at http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: @Eidola Done. Bug number 15914963

Comment: ditto bug number 15915065

Comment: Here is a demo of the magnifying glass bug: https://i.imgur.com/30f67F7.gif